# WP7 Settings to Change Startup Page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, navigation, settings

I have created a Lock.xaml Page where user inserts password... but i want to give the user an option to disable this lock i have tried UriMapper

```
    private void OUriMapper()
    {
        UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
        RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;

        if (.................)
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/Lock.xaml?method=UriMapper, UriKind.Relative);
        else
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/HomePage.xaml?method=UriMapper, UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

And Created Toggle Switch in Settings.xaml now what i want to do is if toggle switch is on then user should directed to Lock.xaml or else HomePage.xaml

I am putting UriMapper code in App.xaml

I am trying to come up with some logic to do this PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `WMAppManifest.xml` remove the `NavigationPage` attribute.

Then you can define in the `Application_Launching` method of App.xaml.cs to which page the user should be directed via `NavigationService.Navigate()` depending on the user's settings.

Works on WP7.8 and should probably work on WP8 as well.